# Add local json file to rails app and use $.getJSON to get it locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to add a local, static JSON file to my rails app and then retrieve the JSON data using `$.getJSON` within another javascript file in the same rails app.

So far I tried adding it to `assets/javascripts/` and `public/` and then running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, however I still haven't successfully loaded the JSON file into my other javascript file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to place a static JSON file in the public directory and load it directly. Assuming a file called `static.json` in the `public` directory, all you need to load it is:

```
$.getJSON('/static.json', function(data) {
  console.debug(data);
});
```

Comment: How can I achieve this if I do not want the json file to be publically accessible?

Comment: Thanks brother, this answer helped me too much. I don't understand why you haven't add the name of folder... But, it's working and anything else matters :D

Comment: @WilliamRomero, If you are asking why the public folder is not included in the path given to getJSON, it's because the public folder is the root of the site.

Comment: Awesome! I really never knew that. But thank you, now I know more about it.