# Angularjs $http.get( file.json ) resulting in No Route matches error (Cloud9 IDE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to render data from a JSON file via $http.get().

But when i run the app, the JSON data isn't rendered, and the developer console shows an error:

---

**ERROR:**
Failed to load. Resource. The server responded with a status of 404 (Not found).
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/phones.json"

**THOUGHTS:**
I've read that $http.get() follows a relative path to the the given URL, so if phones.json is in the same folder as index.html.erb, i can't figure out why its not loading.

I'm wondering if i need to add something to routes.rb.

---

controllers.js

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);
```

---

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :home  
  root 'home#index'
end
```

---

application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title ng-bind-template="Phone Library: {{query}}">Phone Library</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

---

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <ul class="phones">
            <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
                {{ phone.name }}
                <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

---

gems added:

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
```

---

file tree

[image]

---

note:
This is part of an Angularjs tutorial called PhoneCat, chapter5 (url:https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05). Though i made a few detours earlier on to make it work, so unable to follow it exactly at this point.

I'm not an expert in Rails or Angularjs so any advice would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where the actual request is being served? I see the routes, but I don't see where the route `phones.json` is being served from within the Rails app.

Comment: @Mutahhir. Sorry... I don't understand - Can you clarify what you mean by "where the route phones.json is being served from"?
Or if you have an example to help me understand?

Comment: So, for example, you posted the `routes.rb` snippet, but that doesn't have a route that serves `phones.json`, so I was wondering where that is? Rails, I don't think, serves local files without you telling it to, so `phones.json` would have to be a route

Comment: I think the only exception to that is the `public/` folder. If you place the `phones.json` there, that should work, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945284/add-local-json-file-to-rails-app-and-use-getjson-to-get-it-locally

Comment: I see. That worked! :)